# Динамическая память/С++

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать с++. И в процессе возник вопрос, а именно о том чем `nullptr` отличается от `NULL`?

Comment: Что такое "null"? Речь про вот этот [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)?

Comment: Да, речь про NULL

Comment: Даже не буду помечать что дубль в 2^2014. откройте google.com, вставте туда "null vs null pointer in c++" наверное первая ссылка будет sof - если будут тонкости перевода - используйте встроенный в Ваш браузер переводчик

Comment: @Beeen007 В вопросе ничего нет про `nullptr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - поправил)

Comment: @NapoleionidBonaparte Под "null pointer" вы имели в виду `nullptr`, или нет?

Comment: Именно nullptr, ничего другого.

Comment: Надо было так и написать. "Null pointer" - это любой нулевой указатель (типа `int *ptr = 0;`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(К "динамической памяти" все это не имеет никакого прямого отношения.)

1. `nullptr` совсем не обязательно "отличается" от `NULL`. В современном С++, начиная с C++11, макро `NULL` может быть определено именно как `nullptr`.
2. "Классический" `NULL` представляет собой целочисленное константное выражение<sup>1</sup>  со значением `0`, т.е. может использоваться не только в указательных, но также и в арифметических контекстах (в том числе - по ошибке). `nullptr` не приводим к целому типу и в арифметических контекстах использован быть не может<sup>2</sup>.
3. Возможность использования "классического" `NULL` в указательных контекстах базируется на том, что целочисленное константное значение `0` неявно приводимо к указательному типу. Однако такая неявная приводимость не имеет места в контексте аргументов шаблона. Т.е. `NULL` не может выступать в качестве null-pointer constant в списке аргументов шаблона

   ```
   template <void *p> struct S {};

   int main()
   {
     S<NULL> s1;          // Ошибка!
     S<(void *) NULL> s2; // OK
     S<nullptr> s3;       // OK
   }
   ```

   `nullptr` свободен от этого недостатка.

---

<sup>1</sup> - в современном С++ (с момента появления `nullptr`), `NULL` должен быть определен как *целочисленный литерал* со значением `0`. Произвольное целочисленное константное выражение со значением `0` больше не может выступать в роли null-pointer constant. Также в роли null-pointer constant больше не может выступать `false` и `\0`.

<sup>2</sup> - кроме возможности приведения к `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` это дефайн на `0` типа `int`. nullptr имеет тип указателя, что очень важно в некоторых моментах. Очень подробно эту тему рассматривает Мэйерс в своей книге 
Effective Modern C++, очень рекомендую вам её к прочтению.

Comment: *"дефайн на 0 типа int"* Не обязательно, см https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL

Comment: @HolyBlackCat какие компиляторы рискнули поменять этот дефайн с 0 на nullptr? Назовите хоть один? Мне кажется такой шаг может поломать много кода, например, когда есть перегрузка с int и указателем.

Comment: В моем ГЦЦ вообще стоит `#define NULL __null`, где `__null` - что-то встроенное в компилятор. `decltype` говорит, что оно типа `long long`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в любом случае это интегральный тип. Сменить тип NULL интегрального типа на тип указателя вряд ли решиться хоть один компилятор. Я сейчас глянул в последнем msvc, там дефайн на 0.

Comment: `nullptr` не является указателем, однако тип этого литерала имеет встроенные неявные преобразования к любым указателям.

Comment: А ещё кажется у `nullptr_t` был оператор приведения к `bool`.